# Flutter video_player in android tv some videos(Streams) became green

Tags: android, flutter, exoplayer, video-player, flutter-video-player

I am trying to make tv channel streaming app. Most channels works. but some of them always became green or stretched like in the image.
[one of broke channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLl44.jpg)

but this is not happening in mobile phones only android tv. even android that has api 19 or lower they cannot even play video only black screen.
is it problem of exo player? should I switch to another player? or are there anyway to fix it?